# directory-first-search with find

Tags: shell, gnu-findutils, find-util

When `find` iterates directories, they show up in [the order the VFS yields them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23446/which-order-does-find-command-use-to-print-out). Can this order be changed to first traverse directories before looking at files placed beside them?

The `-depth` option is not the solution. It only changes

```
$ find
.
./afile
./directory
./directory/athirdfile
./other-directory
```

to

```
$ find -depth
./afile
./directory/athirdfile
./directory
./other-directory
```

(Note how only the second and third output line swapped places.)

This question instead seeks for a way to produce the following order.

```
./directory/athirdfile
./directory
./other-directory
./afile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your customized output by using 2 `find` commands. First `find` will get everything using `-depth` except files in current directory and 2nd `find` will get just the files from current level.

```
{ find . -depth -mindepth 1; find . -maxdepth 1 -depth -type f; }
```

Comment: A promising approach, but it does not yet work recursively. Subdirectories should also appear before files placed beside them. Chaining the two `find`s together via `-exec` could work, though.

Comment: On my gnu find subdirectories do appear before files of starting directory

Comment: On my system, which is a GNU find over a tmpfs on kernel 4.6.4, `mkdir -p a/b/c`, `touch a/d` followed by `{ find . -depth -mindepth 1; find . -maxdepth 1 -depth -type f; } | tr '\n' ,` outputs `./a/d,./a/b/c,./a/b,./a,`. File `a/d` appears before sibling directory `a/b`.

Comment: Exactly same setup and same commands give me `./a/b/c,./a/b,./a/d,./a,` output. I am using `find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0`

Comment: I tested same set of commands on Ubuntu with `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2` and got same output i.e. `./a/b/c,./a/b,./a/d,./a,`